# uwp: How download files when app is in suspended mode

Tags: c++, uwp

There is queue with links of files to download. I'm trying find the way to continue downloading when application goes to suspend mode.
According to official microsoft documentation suitable class for this is [BackgroundDownloader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader?view=winrt-19041), but it's handles only one current downloading process. It looks wrong to call in loop CreateDownload() method for every link without waiting for the completion of previous links, isn't right?

More logical in my opinion is using [in-process background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task). I see it this way:

1. Implement Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance) method of interface IBackgroundTask (it should stay alive even when app is suspended, right?)
2. Using custom event transmit the queue to the implemented method
3. Inside Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance) method use BackgroundDownloader (by implementing the execution of one instance at a time)

But I'm stuck even with simple implementation for one file downloading. Bellow my Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance) method implementation:

```
void Task::DownloaderTask::Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance ^ taskInstance)
{
    TaskDeferral = taskInstance->GetDeferral();
    std::wstring filename = L"Pleiades_large.jpg";
    Uri^ uri = ref new Uri(ref new Platform::String(L"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Pleiades_large.jpg"));
    Concurrency::create_task(KnownFolders::GetFolderForUserAsync(nullptr, KnownFolderId::PicturesLibrary))
        .then([this, filename, uri](StorageFolder^ picturesLibrary)
    {
        return picturesLibrary->CreateFileAsync(ref new Platform::String(filename.c_str()), CreationCollisionOption::GenerateUniqueName);
    }).then([this, filename, uri](StorageFile^ destinationFile) {
        BackgroundDownloader^ downloader = ref new BackgroundDownloader();
        DownloadOperation^ download = downloader->CreateDownload(uri, destinationFile);

        download->StartAsync();
    }).then([this](Concurrency::task<void> previousTask)
    {
        try
        {
            previousTask.get();
            TaskDeferral->Complete();
        }
        catch (Platform::Exception^ ex)
        {
            wchar_t buffer[1024];
            swprintf_s(buffer, L"Exception: %s", ex->Message);
            OutputDebugString(buffer);
        }
    });
}
```

The code above only creates empty file, but using the same code without BackgroundTask it works correctly. I didn't find any restrictions for BackgroundDownloader inside BackgroundTask.

So, my questions are:

- Is it right way of usage BackgroundTask?
- Is there another approach to solving the problem?
- Is this problem solvable at all?

Comment: @CoCaIceDew Thank you for your answer. It seems as a fallback if something goes wrong with my original plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the cause of the unexpected behavior:
The line of code `TaskDeferral->Complete();` was at the end of the method at first while it should be at the end of async call.
Therefore, initial implementation (published in question) is correct.
**All that had to be done was to Rebuild project.**